# System.Data.SQLite.dll - which version and how to compile?

Tags: .net, sqlite, compilation, system.data.sqlite

I'm writing a windows app using x64 windows. On the dev machine I can export the installer, install the application and it works just fine, no matter whether I compile for Any CPU, x86 or x64 and seemingly no matter what version of System.Data.SQLite.dll I'm using - mixed mode, x64, x86, not mixed-mode...

When transferring the installer to another machine, also x64 Win7, no matter how the application is compiled and no matter what System.Data.SQLite.dll I use.

I get errors ranging from BadImageFormatException to UnsafeNativeMethods depending on which combination I'm using.

Which combination of System.Data.SQLite.dll and CPU compilation should I be using? x64 / x64 seems the logical choice, but surely forcing an x86 compile and using the x86 dll should work too?

Or am I barking totally up the wrong tree?

Thanks

**Edit:** It's only *really* important that the app compile on x64 w7 at least for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. I had to ensure I used the 32-bit version and compiled it as an x86 application (even for Windows 7 x64 systems).

If it helps, the size of the `system.data.sqlite.dll` file was 866 KB (using version 1.0.64 if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks, this turned out to be the problem. Uninstalling System.Data.SQLite completely and installing the 32 bit version seemed to do the trick. Marked this as the answer, cheers!